# Are the military tilted-thrust aircraft in the film Avatar feasible?

Tags: aircraft-design, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

As full-scale aircraft or as models / UAVs / drones?  Is anyone working on making these real or are they fundamentally flawed designs, or needing new materials to be invented?

Answer (score 5):

I presume you're talking about the fictional [Aerospatiale SA-2 Samson](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Aerospatiale_SA-2_Samson). From that page:

> Ducted fan VTOL aircraft have been flown since at least the 1960s. A notable example was the [Bell X-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_X-22), a quad-ducted fan experimental aircraft built for the US military. It has no relation to the later V-22 Osprey tiltrotor. Though successful, no military aircraft since have used that technology.

The Bell X-22 looked like this:

[image]

which has similar overall characteristics to the SA-2 depictions.

Answer (score 2):

They are feasible in as much as the atmosphere on "Pandora" is thicker and the force of gravity is lighter. C.f. [Avatar Wiki](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Pandora)

This allows for both large winged reptiles (?) and smaller tiltrotors than are possible on our current earth.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> There is evidence that our atmosphere was more oxygen-rich in the geologic past and may have been thicker, allowing for similarly large reptiles.

Comment: They're feasible anyway - in fact, I've seen scale models of them fly here on Earth. As long as you have enough power, they're certainly controllable.

Comment: You do know that when you scale down, that because air molecules don't scale down with you, that your model is operating as if it's in a thicker atmosphere.

Comment: Oh my mistake, the V-22 Osprey doesn't work on Earth.... I didn't dispute that a thicker atmosphere would potentially allow a smaller rotor, I disputed the fact that it's ONLY feasible with a thicker atmosphere. Scale physics aren't the important point here, thrust-to-weight is, and that's achievable at model or "full size" scale here on earth

Comment: The osprey is considerably chunkier and less manouverable than the rotorcraft shown.

Comment: Yes, but it's working to a different paradigm and presumably different engine technology. The question wasn't "Can we make a SA-2 from Avatar right now" it was "Is an SA-2 FEASIBLE or FATALLY FLAWED" - it IS feasible and IS NOT fatally flawed. You could, with a big enough research budget and a few years, develop one here on Earth now.

Comment: Not sure that the power/thrust ratio would work with ducted fans given our current atmosphere and gravity. It's a matter of physics, not just budgets. We're now moving out of aviation and into scifi.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are certainly feasible. In fact, one basically exists already: [the V-22 Osprey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Boeing_V-22_Osprey).

The main difference being that the V-22 has ailerons for roll control and wings for lift in forward flight.

Power isn't a problem, it's just a multirotor helicopter... think Chinook, on a different axis. And control, for the most part, isn't a major issue.

1. Differential power to the two motors provides Roll control, similar to a quadcopter
2. Rotating the rotors slightly forward/back and/or something similar to a cyclic on a conventional helicopter allows (similar to the Osprey tiltrotor):

   - Forward/reverse flight (if tilted together)
   - Yaw control (if tilted in opposing directions... think tank tracks
3. If attached in away that they can be angled up/down, pivoting on the attachment to the fuselage, the vehicle can "strafe" (ie lateral sideways movement)
4. Pitch when in forward/reverse flight is provided by the tail stabilisers. In the hover it could presumably be controlled to some extent by means similar to a conventional helicopter's cyclic, shifting weight, or by an additional small rotor near the tail, if you didn't want to be 100% true to the movie model

[Here's a working model](http://youtu.be/U0OmZA2vQ14), for example. I don't believe there are any full size models, but the Osprey is "close enough" to prove the concept.